# Статистика по HTTP Геокодеру Яндекс API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Облазил документацию и не могу понять как получить статистику по использованию HTTP Геокодера по API.
В личном кабинете данные вижу, но нужно мониторить это значение.

Может такого функционала вообще нет?

Comment: Пока статистика доступна только в Кабинете разработчика

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[API Кабинета разработчика](https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth.html) теперь отдает limits отдельно для **apimaps_http_geocoder_daily** — это и есть нужный вам параметр.